# Garbage Collection - Mutex

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, mutex, collect

Based on my research, the general rule of thumb is not to mess with GC (i.e. don't call GC.Collect()). We have a server based process that processes huge XML documents - the memory never gets released. The code looks like this:

```
while (!abort)
{
  mutex.WaitOne();

  //sets abort to true to end the process itself
  DoSomeWork();

  mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

After DoSomeWork() runs, the memory is never released. Is this happening because the GC is not getting any "alone time" to do its thing? Should we be calling GC.Collect after DoSomeWork() to force a GC?

Thanks

Comment: A garbage collector normally does not release memory until it feels it could be needed. If memory is aplenty, garbage collector does not run.

Comment: C#, .Net. Sorry - should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `GC.Collect` in a dev environment and see what happens.  If the memory doesn't go down you have a memory leak.  It may mean you're not releasing objects that you're actually done with and that there are references to them somewhere; or it could be that you're not properly disposing of unmanaged memory properly.  If it does go down it means you just need to give the GC time.

If the objects are indeed eligible for collection (as per the previous test) consider if it's imperative for the memory to go down right away, or if it's acceptable to wait a few hundred milliseconds for the GC to be scheduled.  Are you getting OOM errors; are applications being swapped to disk as a result of this?  If no, consider just waiting for the GC to do it's thing.

Also ask yourself if performance is an issue, or just memory.  Calling `Collect` manually is likely to harm performance, not help it.

Answer (score 0):

You should feel free to call GC.Collect after some process has been completed that killed a large amount of objects. Processing XML documents is a classic example of a case where this is the correct thing to do.
Anyone who tells you **never call GC.Collect** is simply holding to what they have been taught which is *usually* true but not *always*.

Comment: Well the OP said that "the memory is never released" which would indicate the objects aren't even eligible for collection, as opposed to the memory just not being release quickly enough.

Comment: Yes, I am getting OOM errors (eventually, i.e. after processing x # of large documents). Here is a "dumb" question – this function (with the mutex.WaitOne) is being called on the main thread. Given this, will GC have an opportunity to do its thing?